# NetFilter ConnTrack FTP helper alernative fo handle FTPS

Tags: linux, iptables, ftp, ftps, nf-conntrack

I've been using `nf_conntrack_ftp` module successfully (though rarely), but now I have to deal with TLS-encrypted FTP - this renders that helper useless an I would have to resort to opening the firewall statically, which I'd rather avoid.

Are there any generic `nf_conntrack*` modules that would work in this case? The scenario I'm interested in is *if there is a connection to port 21/tcp, allow connection to any other port to that remote host*